# What wix elements and attributes must be set to let a user Modify an msi package inside a Bundle?

Tags: wix, wix3

Using a wix bundle we have included our installer which has several custom features. It doesn't seem that from add/remove programs a user can choose to modify that installer. The outline of our wix code is as follows.

```
<Wix ...>
  <Bundle ...>
    <Chain>
        <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx451Webz" />
        <PackageGroupRef Id="vcredists" />
        <RollbackBoundary />
        <PackageGroupRef Id='AppPackageGroup'/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
  <Fragment Id='AppFragment'>
      <PackageGroup Id='AppPackageGroup'>
        <MsiPackage Id='AppMsiPackage'
                DisplayName='$(var.ApplicationName) $(var.VersionNumber)'
                DisplayInternalUI='yes'
                ForcePerMachine='yes'
                InstallCondition='1'
                SourceFile='app.msi'
                Visible='yes'
                Vital='yes'>
      </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

What needs to happen to allow the user to modify this msi and chose different features?

Comment: How about EnableFeatureSelection="yes" under <MsiPackage>?

Comment: So that doesn't have any effect when the modify action is taken.